# My error : error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 . And this: An argument for 'params' was not provided

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8, viewchild

**customer-list.component.ts**

onLoadCustomers() {
const customersReq = this.customerService.getCustomers()

**customer.servise.ts**

getCustomers(params: any): Observable {
return this.http.post(`${this.api}api/v1/customers/query`, params)
}

Comment: it seems you need to send params during ```getCustomers(params:any)``` api call, can you elaborate more your questions and share more relevant code ?

Comment: if you don't want to pass prams make it optional or pas default value because your function needs some value to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
onLoadCustomers() { const customersReq = this.customerService.getCustomers({})
```

Even if you don't want to add any params to the call the function in the service
is expecting an argument, you can simply pass an empty object as params.

Solution 2:

```
getCustomers(params?: any): Observable { return this.http.post(${this.api}api/v1/customers/query, params || {}) }
```

You can also make the parameter optional by just adding a "?" but in that case, you need to provide a default value if "params" is undefined.